# Can't find user without ID - form error in Rails 3 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am working on a website like Gumtree.com, where Users create Posts, highlighting their various needs (e.g. I need a photographer on day X).

Having some trouble with the Messaging functionality. I am using the Simple Private Messaging plugin.

Problem is in the form that Users fill out to send a message / respond to a post. I get the following error when I try to access /messages/new:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MessagesController#new
Couldn't find User without an ID
```

Attaching my models below - grateful for any advice!

Thanks,

Faisal

**MESSAGES CONTROLLER**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

before_filter :set_user

def index
if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
  @messages = @user.sent_messages
else
  @messages = @user.received_messages
end
end

def show
@message = Message.read_message(params[:id], current_user)
end

def new
@message = Message.new

if params[:reply_to]
  @reply_to = @user.received_messages.find(params[:reply_to])
  unless @reply_to.nil?
    @message.to = @reply_to.sender.login
    @message.subject = "Re: #{@reply_to.subject}"
    @message.body = "\n\n*Original message*\n\n #{@reply_to.body}"
  end
end
end

def create
@message = Message.new(params[:message])
@message.sender = @user
@message.recipient = User.find_by_login(params[:message][:to])

if @message.save
  flash[:notice] = "Message sent"
  redirect_to user_messages_path(@user)
else
  render :action => :new
end
end

def delete_selected
if request.post?
  if params[:delete]
    params[:delete].each { |id|
      @message = Message.find(:first, :conditions => ["messages.id = ? AND (sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?)", id, @user, @user])
      @message.mark_deleted(@user) unless @message.nil?
    }
    flash[:notice] = "Messages deleted"
  end
  redirect_to :back
end
end

private
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end
end
```

**MESSAGE MODEL**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

is_private_message

attr_accessor :to

end
```

**USER MODEL**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :posts  
has_one :profile
has_private_messages

attr_accessible :email

validates_presence_of :email
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :message =>"Hmm, that email's already taken"
validates_format_of :email, :with => /^([^\s]+)((?:[-a-z0-9]\.)[a-z]{2,})$/i, :message => "Hi! Please use a valid email"


end
```

**MESSAGE>NEW VIEW**

```
<% form_for @message, :url => user_messages_path(@user) do |f| %>
<p>
To:<br />
    <%= f.text_field :to %>
    <%= error_message_on @message, :to %>
</p>
<p>
Subject:<br />
<%= f.text_field :subject %>
<%= error_message_on @message, :subject %>
</p>
<p>
  Message<br />
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
        <%= error_message_on @message, :body %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= submit_tag "Send" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you remember how you fixed the issue? I'm using the same plugin you did and have the same problem. I have tried setting @user to User.first, User.find(1) etc but no luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that your page for new messages receives `:user_id` in it's `params`? Even if it is true, I doubt that this is was your intention because anyone can pretend to be another user by just passing another `:user_id`.

So your line in the bottom:

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id]) # I think it's the cause of your error -- no :user_id is passed
```

seems like has to be:

```
@user = User.find(session[:user_id])
```

I suppose you've heard about sessions.

Comment: Just simple replacement wont's solve your problem. Try to test: pass any valid id to this `find()` method and see if your action works. If so -- you didn't pass `:user_id` in the first place.

Comment: Just replace `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` with `@user = User.first`