# Couldn't find [model] without and id, Rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have followed the instructions and have tried to install [simple-private-messages](https://github.com/jongilbraith/simple-private-messages) gem for Rails 3.2.3 .

I know there are many questions about "couldn't find [model] without an id", but they are slightly old and I've been unable to make solutions/ideas posted in any other questions work.

I've found the same problem and same gem being used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217166/cant-find-user-without-id-form-error-in-rails-3-project#comment14004559_10217166), but there is no clear answer provided. I also think the problem is not caused by the specific gem.

Steps I've done to install the plugin:

```
Added plugin to gemfile, ran bundle install
rails generate simple_private_messages:model User Pmessage
Added this line to user.rb : has_private_messages :class_name => "Pmessage"
rails generate simple_private_messages:scaffold User Pmessage
Uncommented this line in pmessage.rb : attr_accessor :to
```

I then added this to my routes.rb :
match '/pmessages', to: 'pmessages#index'

Accessing /pmessages results in this error message:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PmessagesController#index Couldn't
>   find User without an ID Rails.root: /home/user/RoR/railsapp
>   app/controllers/pmessages_controller.rb:59:in `set_user'

pmessages_controller contains a **set_user** method which is the root of thee problem.

```
private
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params:[user_id])
  end
```

I have a valid user record with id=1, but changing the troublesome line to **@user = User.find(1)** and accessing /pmessages results in this error message:

> Showing /home/user/RoR/railsapp/app/views/pmessages/_inbox.html.erb
>   where line #26 raised: undefined method `login' for #User:0xab4dc3c
>   Extracted source (around line #26):

Assigning value to User this way or any other way still results in the same error message:

```
@user = User.first
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your route should be like

```
resources :users do
  resources :pmessages
end
```

So there is `user_id` on each request to `/users/:user_id/pmessages`.

Alternatively, your `set_user` method might look like:

```
def set_user
  @user = current_user
end
```

So `@user` always points to current user (and route can still be what you set it to).

Second, your `User` model has no field called login. If there is `username` attribute in your model, you might add this to the model: `alias_attribute :login, :username` or if you want the email to be login: `alias_attribute :login, :email`.